# wcf (sql server) + listener en android studio

Tags: sql, android-studio, web, wcf, servidor

Les quería hacer una consulta del paradigma que estoy usando para trabajar mi aplicación con respecto a la información que maneja: Básicamente, cuando quiero actualizar la información tengo que llamar a mi web service para actualizar los datos que almaceno con sqlite. El tema es que llegas a un punto en donde esto es incomodo e inmanejable a nivel proceso y usuario.

Tengo entendido que por ej. FIREBASE te provee de una API donde manejas listeners. En donde cualquier cambio que sufra tu DATO (NoSql) se dispara (como un trigger) los cambios a todos los dispositivos en tiempo real.

Mi consulta era para saber si hay algo similar que se pueda hacer con sql server como motor? o alguna recomendación/consejo para ver que camino tomar sin tener que pagar o evaluar si no me queda otra alternativa.